# One form, but multple action buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form where a user fils in some details, and submits the data with a submit button.

I need to add a new button to my form, which does a post back, passing the model back, adds some items to a List<> (which is a property of the model), and then refreshes the page.

How do I route the post to a different action than the form's post method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name of the submit button as a parameter in your action.

Let's say you have the following submit buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnCompare" value="Compare" />
<input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" />
```

You can capture both of them in one action and then check to see which one was clicked:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SavedResults(Results myResults, string btnCompare, string btnSave) {
  if (btnCompare != null) {
    //btnCompare was clicked. Do related stuff here.
  }
  else if (btnSave != null) {
    //btnSave was clicked. Do related stuff here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use two different buttons with same name  but different value and use this button name in your post action on controller with condition.

use this in your view

use following code on controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(ModelName model, string Action)
{
if(Action.Equals("button1")
{
}
if(Action.Equals("buttons")
{
//write your code to add items in list
model.itemList.Add(newitem);
}
return RedirectToAction("ActionName",model);
}
```